# OpenGL - glGenerateMipmap before loading texture data

Tags: c#, opengl, mipmaps

In my code I called `glGenerateMipmap` before actually loading texture data (with `glTexImage2D`), yet I noticed it still seems to work...

Why is that? Does calling `glGenerateMipmap` cause future `glTexImage2D` calls to create mipmap data as well?

Code (I use C# and OpenTK):

```
int id = GL.GenTexture();
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int) TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int) TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (float)TextureMinFilter.LinearMipmapLinear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (float)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

// if I comment this line it results in triangles being black - suggesting mipmaps are being used
// (otherwise it works just fine)
GL.GenerateMipmap(GenerateMipmapTarget.Texture2D);

BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bmpData.Width, bmpData.Height, 0,
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmpData.Scan0);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Comment: It's not supposed to work that way, but anything's possible when you invoke undefined behavior. `glGenerateMipmaps (...)` takes image LOD 0 and generates the mipchain by downsampling it for all remaining LODs down to 1x1. That of course only makes sense when image LOD 0 is allocated, which it is not until you call `glTexImage2D`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glGenerateMipmap()` takes the **current content** of the base level image (where the base level is the level set as `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL`, 0 by default), and generates all the mipmap levels from base level + 1 to the maximum level.

This means that `glGenerateMipmap()` has no effect on future calls to `glTexImage2D()`. If you want your mipmaps to be updated after modifying the texture data with calls like `glTexImage2D()` or `glTexSubImage2D()`, you have to call `glGenerateMipmap()` again.

If it looks like your mipmaps are update automatically, I can think of two possible explanations:

1. Your OpenGL implementation does something that is not required by the spec. In fact I would argue that it's broken, because it's not supposed to change texture levels that are not explicitly modified by your `glTex[Sub]Image2D()` calls. The previously generated mipmaps should remain unchanged.
2. You're not really using mipmapping. Either your `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is not set to use mipmapping, or `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`/`GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD` are set to not use mipmaps. Or even more likely, your textures are just not minified based on their dimensions and the size they are drawn at.

There is a `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP` texture parameter in the compatibility profile. That one causes mipmaps to be generated automatically anytime the texture content changes.